# Why is every item in build.gradle gray?

Tags: java, android, spring, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm creating a new spring boot project with gradle in intellij idea. After the project is created, each item in the build.gradle and settings.gradle are found to be gray.
The picture is below, you can see the grayed out part and the underline on the picture.

[image]

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 x64 (Ultimate Edition)
Java8
gradle wrapper version gradle-5.4.1-bin
spring boot version 2.1.7.RELEASE
windows10 17763

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

The project is working properly and there is no error

Comment: I had a similar issue with everything in build.gradle being greyed out, however the settings.gradle file looked fine. My issue was that the project wasn't included in settings.gradle, and once I included it everything got resolved. In this case however it seems like settings.gradle is greyed out as well.

Comment: Probably an IntelliJ hiccup. I had the same issue just deleted all IntelliJ files and reimported the project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to click "Reload All Gradle projects" button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the project correctly with Gradle? If not, delete the folder from where you saved it ( if you did git or something similar to pull it in ) and make sure that the folder name matches the same in the settings.gradle file. Re-import the project and opening it in IntelliJ should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it. The problem was, gradle was in the wrong directory and could not download dependencies.

- If you download the spring boot project, it comes as zip.
- If you unzip it you have two nested folders: **myApplication** > myApplication > src, gradle etc.
- Remove the first **myApplication**. Your project structure should be like myApplication > src, gradle etc.
- Then right click on "src" and Mark Directory as -> Source Root
- Go to build.gradle and build the project. You should be able to see gradle on the right sidebar of Intellij.